# can I install mint along with ubuntu on my 32GB pendrive?

Tags: usb-installation

I have installed ubuntu on my pen drive and now I can boot from my pendrive. Now I want the same to be done for MINT. So can I install MINT on the same pendrive along with UBUNTU? Pendrive size 32GB.

Comment: Is your pendrive Ubuntu your only installation? If so I'll have to change my post below. Short version: you'll probably need another pendrive.

Answer (score 0):

You can install as many different live distros as you like on a pendrive using Multisystem.

It is very well maintained, and there are frequent automatic updates once you have the repositories installed.

You can get the source here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/

But you can also install and keep it updated it via Ubuntu package manager by downloading the following, extracting it and running it as root (be warned!):

http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz

The only thing is that you will have to start with a freshly-formatted USB, then use Multisystem to install Ubuntu and Mint. However it will mean you won't have to manually configure Grub2 yourself, which would be another way to do things.